# Calculate the probabilities of appearing even or odd numbers in a predefined set of spins

Tags: probability

I am doing some experiments on the probabilities of a roulette.

If I have $\frac{18}{37}$ even numbers and $\frac{18}{37}$ odd numbers. $0$ is not considered as even in this case but as a neutral number.
Also I know that in $100$ spins, $30$ were even and $70$ were odd.
In a total of $200$ spins how do I calculate the probabilities of how many even and odd numbers may appear in the next $100$ spins.

Is this possible to calculate?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If the roulette is fair (all numbers are equiprobable, and all spins are independent), then the probabilities for the "next 100 spins" is just the probabilities for any 100 spins. The fact about 30/70 even/odd results in previous 100 spins would be (besides very improbable) irrelevant.

Comment: If you get $30$ even and $70$ odd numbers in $100$ spins, your roulette wheel is likely to be seriously defective.

Comment: @leonbloy that s exactly what I wanted to hear, how can you say it is very improbable? is there a formula to understand the improbability of that event to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that even and odd both have probability $\frac 12$ of getting 'drawn'. (Since the result we will obtain is VERY significant, this assumption won't affect the result.) We now have the binomial distribution with $p=\frac 12$ and $n=100$. We want to know the probability of getting more then 70 even spins or less then 30 even spins (since we are calculating the two sided exceedance probability). This can be done with mathematica, and gives a probability of $0.0000785014$. (This is calculated with `2*CDF[BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2], 30] // N` using mathematica.) When using a $1\%$ significance level, this result is significant, so you may assume the roulette wheel is biased.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot directly answer the question for you (other than saying it is still a 50/50 proposition) but I do want to say that It is doubtful that there is anything wrong with the wheel, even though the distribution you mention does have a lower probability of occuring than a more even distribution.

Likelihood of any individual spin coming black or red is 18 out of 37 (48.65%).  In a dataset of 100 spins, perfect distribution would therefore give you 48.65 Red, 48.65 Black & 2.7 Green.  However, since a prior spin (or 100 prior spins) is not predictive of the next spin (or the next 100) any correlation is an illusion. That illusion is how casinos get built.

Equalization of black vs red over a large dataset is likely but the next 100 spins is probably not large enough for that to occur. This anomaly you described was a 30% probability, which isn't that unusual an occurence, and it comes back to almost perfect distribution if over the next 20 sets of 100 spins, black hits an average of 50 times and red hits an average of 46 (ignoring green as you do with the 30/70 analogy). That average could still easily be reached even if there were another 30/70 split in the next hundred (it would only take 990 black vs 900 red over the next 1900 spins to equalize the distribution of 60/140 over the first 200, and that actually has a probability of 47.9% given the equation 900/1900).

To put in real world perspective, I have seen perfectly balanced automated wheels have a specific number "hit" only once in 330+ spins (probability of this occuring is .015% chance given the equation (37/38) to the 330th power)). To see this kind of anomaly in action, all you have to do is to look at the electronic board above the table in most casinos and find that there are almost always "cold" numbers that have only hit 1-4 times in the last 300 spins. Given that these ridiculous improbabilities correct themselves over time, it is highly unlikely that the 30/70 split over a very limited dataset will immediately correct itself in the next 100 spins.

Think of it this way, casinos will kick you out for counting cards at a blackjack table but actively publish the results of a large distribution of previous spins at a roulette table, as well as provide cards so you can "chart" results. They do that to try and entice you to see patterns or think you can get an edge so just don't fall for it.